# Excessive CPU use of azure mdsd

Tags: azure

I am running a Kubernetes cluster on Azure deployed using "azure acs ...". Recently I noticed that the pods on one of the nodes were not responsive and that the CPU on the node was maxed out. I logged in, executed top and found that a process called "mdsd" was using up all available CPU.
When I killed that process with "sudo kill -9", the CPU usage returned to normal and my pods were working fine.
It seems to me like "mdsd" is part of the Azure linux monitoring framework. I installed omi-1.4.0-6.ssl_100.ulinux.x64.deb.
Is there a way to make sure that mdsd is not eating up all my CPU and stopping my pods from working properly?